# Calculating Run time of a program in clock cycles

Tags: assembly, x86

If an assembly program is as follows:

[image]

Would one be correct in saying that there is 74 clock cycles?
Where my confusion arises is where it says  16 (Back) or 4 (Forward) clock cycles. In my case how i got 74 clock cycles was i just added up every clock cycle. Both back and forward ones. Struggling to find any info on this topic so any input would help.

Comment: I don't know what back/forward are supposed to mean here. But there are many other things to take into consideration to count the clock cycles. Is there a pipeline? Are these jumps near or far? Is there a cache?

Comment: "run time" usually involves total time, so if you do `mov ax,2 loopLabel: dec ax jnz loopLabel`, it will take 4 + 2 + 16 + 2 + 4 cycles (instructions executed are: `mov, dec, jnz(jumps), dec, jnz(skips)`). If you will go instruction by instruction (in your code), it will take only few hundreds years to count them all, so start rather today... to understand how many times each instruction will execute and why.

Comment: But "back/forward" with `jnz` is sort of stupid... it doesn't work like that, it can jump both back and forward, the direction depends on the encoded offset. In your code all the requested jumps are point "back" toward start of code, but it would make more sense to talk about executed/skipped conditional jump, without direction.  BTW, 4th link when I googled "assembly cycles counting": https://ucexperiment.wordpress.com/2013/06/15/the-lost-art-of-cycle-counting/  (looks explained enough to help you with yours, even if it's for different CPU)

Comment: Something you can count is number of instructions executed, what you cannot determine is clock cycles.

Comment: I'm guessing this question is based on some ancient 1980s CPU, probably 80x86, before there were such things as branch prediction, caches, multiple execution units, etc, when life was much more deterministic...

Comment: Even on the 8088, where strict instruction timings were given, they were rules-of-thumb *at best*, and more often, pure fiction. You had all sorts of "cycle eaters" ([as Michael Abrash called them](http://www.jagregory.com/abrash-zen-of-asm)), things like the DRAM refresh and video wait states, not to mention the incredibly short prefetch queue. And now, on modern processors, it's *completely impossible* to predict. Cycle counting is a complete waste of time. Write the code, and then **time it**. Use real-world timing measurements (`RDTSC` on Pentium and later), instead of trying to speculate.

Comment: As far as this "back"/"forward" thing… You are probably getting two different things mixed up. First, on older processors that used static branch prediction, backwards branches were statically predicted as taken, while forwards branches were not-taken. Second, falling through was always faster than branching. Therefore, you wanted to arrange it so that the most likely case was falling through (not branching) for optimum speed. The official cycle counts never depended on the direction of the branch, though. It was whether the branch was taken or not taken.

Comment: For the 8088/8086, a *taken* conditional jump was indeed officially given as taking 16 cycles, whereas a *not taken* conditional jump was 4 cycles. That matches your numbers exactly. A non-conditional `JMP` was always (again, officially) 15 cycles, so you paid 1 extra cycle for the conditional aspect of the jump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering your question, I would like to say that this method does not apply to any modern pipelined/superscalar/out-of-order processor design. Some instructions have zero latency, such as register-register `MOV` instructions on Core i7.

The back / forward comments refer to whether the branch is taken ("back") or not taken ("forward"). The latency of the branch depends on which direction it goes.

The program is going to take far more than 74 clock cycles. You should be summing the latency of every instruction that *executes*, and most instructions in the listing will execute more than once. For example, the first `DEC` will execute 65535*65535*65535 times, which is roughly 2^48.

Since your program consists of loops, the proper way to analyze this would be to start with the innermost loop and calculate its latency, and then proceed to the outer loops. The innermost loop starts at the label `back1` and contains two instructions, a `DEC` and a `JNZ`. Since it executes 65535 iterations, the latency of this loop is 65535*2 (`DEC`) + 65534*16 (taken `JNZ`) + 1*4 (not taken `JNZ`), which works out to 1179618.

This loop is embedded in an outer loop starting at the label `back2` and containing a `MOV`, the inner loop, a `DEC`, and a `JNZ`. You can work out the run time for this loop similarly to the previous calculation. After that, you'll work out the run time for the loop starting at `back3`. Finally, don't forget the first `MOV` instruction, which is not contained in any of the loops and executes exactly once.

Comment: *"The latency of the branch depends on which direction it goes."* I think you're missing a "not" in there. See [my comment up on the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474844/calculating-run-time-of-a-program-in-clock-cycles#comment74045839_43474844). The direction doesn't matter for the cycle count, only whether the branch is taken or not-taken. The only reason the direction matters is when you have static branch prediction—and the 8088/8086 didn't have any sort of branch prediction, static or otherwise. All that mattered was that branching emptied the tiny prefetch queue.

Comment: Also, when you're counting cycles like this, you are counting *throughput* (specifically, reciprocal throughput), not latency. Latency comes into play when you have a dependency chain, and later instructions are waiting on the results of previous instructions. That is certainly an issue on modern processors, and why latency matters now (often more than throughput in real-world performance assessments), but didn't matter on the 8088/8086 because it wasn't pipelined and certainly had no out-of-order (OOO) execution! You misuse the term latency several times in your answer.

Comment: The OP didn't specify which processor. If the problem is for an existing design, which seems unlikely, it is obviously earlier than the pipelined 80486, but it's probably not the 8086, either. The 8086 had cycle times on the order of 10 clocks for most operations, not 4. The comments clearly indicate a difference in execution time depending on which direction the branch goes. Since we've been given the cycle times for every instruction in comments, I'd rather not speculate.

Comment: Latency and reciprocal throughput are equal on non-superscalar/non-OOO designs; you cannot execute the next instruction until the current one completes. I would agree with everything that you've said if we were talking about a modern processor, but then the OP's problem wouldn't even make sense. Since this cannot apply to any x86 design in roughly the last 25 years, I suspect that this is some sort of homework assignment.

Comment: The cycle times given in the comments are for the 8088/8086. The cycle times on those processors are officially the same. In practice, of course, the 8088 is slower due to its limited 8-bit bus and smaller prefetch queue, but Intel's times don't take that into account. And it makes some degree of sense that the OP is targeting 8088/8086, since that's what many emulators emulate, often pursuing a high degree of cycle-exactness. I understand your line of thinking about latency and throughput being equivalent, but the term latency wasn't used back then, so I think it's still confusing.